# Import fixed text file into excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm working with importing a fixed text file into excel file using VBA.
I had a problem fixing the fitting of columns (auto fit) also with the decimal of numbers.

I have a Decimal as much as this **5027.1202024.0000.0000.000.0000.0000.0000** and would like to simplified to just 5027.12 since my columns is not fitting and just separating. is there another way besides declaring several arrays and fixing it's width? the text file is somehow fixed already.
I'm still new to vba I would appreaciate every help. Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportPrepayment()
    Dim fpath
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim wkbAll As Workbook
    Dim wkbTemp As Workbook
    Dim sDelimiter As String

    'Call import_TExtFileR12

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    sDelimiter = "|"

    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename _
      (FileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
      MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Text Files to Open")

    If TypeName(fpath) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No Files were selected"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fpath(x))
    wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set wkbAll = ActiveWorkbook
    wkbTemp.Close (False)
    wkbAll.Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    x = x + 1

    While x <= UBound(fpath)
        Set wkbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=fpath(x))
        With wkbAll
            wkbTemp.Sheets(1).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(x).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=sDelimiter
        End With
        x = x + 1
    Wend


Range("A17:XFD" & x).Delete shift:=xlUp
 'Range("A1").Value = "Supplier Name"
   ' Range("C1").Value = "Supplier Number"
    'Range("D1").Value = "Inv Curr Code"
    'Range("E1").Value = "Payment Cur Code"
    'Range("F1").Value = "Invoice Type"
    'Range("G1").Value = "Invoice Number"
    'Range("H1").Value = "Voucher Number"
    'Range("I1").Value = "Invoice Date"
    'Range("J1").Value = "GL Date"
    'Range("K1").Value = "Invoice Amount"
    'Range("L1").Value = "Witheld Amount"
    'Range("M1").Value = "Amount Remaining"
    'Range("N1").Value = "Description"
    'Range("O1").Value = "Account Number"
    'Range("P1").Value = "Invoice Amt"
    'Range("Q1").Value = "Withheld Amt"
    'Range("R1").Value = "Amt Remaining"
    'Range("S1").Value = "User Name"


Call ProcessUsedRange
Columns.EntireColumn.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set wkbAll = Nothing
    Set wkbTemp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
Sub ProcessUsedRange()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim regex As Object, Match As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{3}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}"
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If regex.Test(r.Text) Then
            For Each Match In regex.Execute(r.Value)
                r.Value = "'" & Replace(r.Value, Match.Value, "")
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry that it took so long to get back to you but I posted another answer.

Comment: Hi Thomas above is my update code plus your code (Thanks again!) now my problem is I have to omit those extra headers just fit every column since it has  a lot of pages I'm not sure how to loop or is loop being used since it will be used over and over again with additional pages in text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `TextToColumns` or `Workbooks.OpenText`; just read the text file and process the data.

[image]

```
Sub ImportPrepayment2()
    Dim fpath As Variant
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Text As String
    On Error GoTo terminatemsg

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = Excel.ActiveSheet

    fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="text Files(*.txt; *.txt), *.txt; *.txt", Title:="open")

    If fpath = False Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Text = getTextfileData(fpath)
    If Len(Text) Then
        ProcessData Text
        AdjustDates
    Else
        MsgBox fpath & " is empty", vbInformation, "Import Cancelled"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets(1).Move Before:=wb.Sheets(1)

terminatemsg:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub

Sub ProcessData(Text As String)
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
    Dim data, vLine

    data = Split(Text, vbCrLf)
    x = 2
    Range("A1:R1").Value = Array("Supplier Name", "Supplier Number", "Inv Curr Code CurCode", "Payment CurCode", "Invoice Type", "Invoice Number", "Voucher Number", "Invoice Date", "GL Date", "Invoice Amount", "Withheld Amount", "Amount Remaining", "Description", "Account Number", "Invoice", "Withheld", "Amt", "User")

    For y = 0 To UBound(data)
        If InStr(data(y), "|") Then
            vLine = Split(data(y), "|")
            If Not Trim(vLine(0)) = "Supplier" Then

                For z = 0 To UBound(vLine)
                    vLine(z) = Trim(vLine(z))

                    If vLine(z) Like "*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*" Then vLine(z) = Left(vLine(z), InStr(vLine(z), ".") + 2)

                Next
                Cells(x, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vLine) + 1).Value = vLine
                x = x + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub

Sub AdjustDates()
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 2 To Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        If Cells(x, "R") = vbNullString Then Cells(x, "M").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next

End Sub

Function getTextfileData(FILENAME As Variant) As String
    Const ForReading = 1
    Dim fso, MyFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FILENAME, ForReading)
    getTextfileData = MyFile.ReadAll
    MyFile.Close
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, sorry again, it worked it's just that some of the datas that should be under description is going in column "Amount Remaining"

Comment: Hi Thomas. You are great!!! It worked with User Name column. it moved. I notice the reason why the description values is going with the amount remaining is because of the splitting. it doesn't have the "|".

Answer (score 0):

Add this code before `Columns.EntireColumn.AutoFit`.

```
Sub ProcessUsedRange()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim regex As Object, Match As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Pattern = "\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{3}.\d{4}.\d{4}.\d{4}"
        .Global = True
    End With

    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If regex.Test(r.Text) Then
            For Each Match In regex.Execute(r.Value)
                'The apostrophe is to keep the data formatted as text
                r.Value = "'" & Replace(r.Value, Match.Value, "")
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You should also change

```
MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
```

to

```
If Err.Number <> 0 then MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
```

Comment: Hi Thomas you're such a charmer. but this I tried your code. What I need is to Omit those extra headers (those not in need) let me combine my new code into yours. but still not getting what I need. By the way your help is much appreciated. Thanks.